# Удаление старых комментариев - вандализм?

Tags: обсуждение, комментарии, удаление-комментариев

Время от времени, у меня (модератора), выскакивает автоматическая тревога типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смысл тревоги сводится к тому, что некто (правда хорошо известно кто) спустя N лет выставляет массовые тревоги (до 20-30 в день) с просьбой удалить комментарии к старым ответам/вопросам с формулировкой *нет необходимости*. Я обычно такие тревоги отклоняю, если только тревога не выставлена ТС. Очевидно, другие модераторы позволяют удалять комментарии. Или же тот же самый персонаж делает многочисленные правки старых ответов, причем по большей части правки малоосмысленные.

Свою точку зрения не полезные/бесполезные комментарии я уже обозначал раньше. Повторю еще раз: считаю, что комментарии, иногда даже и не совсем относящиеся к вопросу частью человеческого общения и не вижу смысла в их удалении, если только об этом не просит автор вопроса.

Внимание вопрос: что делать модератору в таких случаях. Вариантов не так много:

1. Позволять товарищу и дальше редактировать/удалять комментарии
2. Влепить ему бан, за вандализм?
3. Что-то еще?

Comment: Я лично не против комментариев в процессе обсуждения вопросов / ответов, но когда вопрос решен / ответ приведен в окончательный вид - лучше избавляться от рудиментарных комментариев чтобы людям пришедшим из поиска было проще воспринимать информацию :)

Comment: Простите, а в чем заключается *вандализм*, почему вы используете это слово, разве происходит действие (удаление), наносится непосредственный вред, или все же только тревоги ставятся? Если другие модераторы по тревогам удаляют лишнее - так это вопрос к ним. Если вам не нравятся тревоги - не реагируйте на них или отклоняйте. Если вам кажется, что бесполезные тревоги мешают модерировать - вот это уже проблема!

Comment: Кстати, *"Или же тот же самый персонаж делает многочисленные правки старых ответов, причем по большей части правки малоосмысленные."* - стоит убрать, чтобы не распыляться в вопросе/ответах. Вопрос про ценность комментариев достаточно целен и вполне сформулирован, не нужно его размывать дополнениями типа "а еще *некто* пишет вы с маленькой буквы и громко сморкается, допустимо ли это?"

Comment: Эм.. Эта тревога вроде не об этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта тревога сработала на то, что человек массово удаляет свои комментарии. При этом он одновременно помечает все соседние комментарии как более ненужные независимо от содержимого. На мой взгляд это действительно вандализм и такие тревоги должны отклоняться. Возможно, стоит так же что-то предпринять, чтобы он перестал удалять комментарии.

Comment: Согласен, что достаточно отметить только один комментарий или сам пост флагом. Это точно стоит сообщить пользователю в сообщении. Остальное - на мой взгляд волюнтаризм.

Comment: Уведомил участника.

Answer (score 6):

> Позволять товарищу и дальше редактировать/удалять комментарии

Да, т.к. бесполезные комментарии или комментарии, которые уже не актуальны, нужно удалять.

> Влепить ему бан, за вандализм?

Это не вандализм, а норма. Комментарии нужны только в момент обсуждения вопроса. Как только вопрос решён, их можно удалять. Очень мало комментариев, которые нужно оставлять после решения вопроса.

Бан за это — наплевательское отношение к правилам и должности модератора.

Comment: объясните пожалуйста что такое «вахтерство» и кто такие «вахтеры»

Comment: @Danis старожилы, которые пытаются свою точку зрения протолкнуть, хотя для этих вещей уже есть правила и решение сообщества. Поправил формулировку, чтобы не смущать.

Answer (score 6):

Если комментарий **не относится** к вопросу и больше **не нужен** — он должен быть **удален**.

В этом и смысл тревоги. **Для общения — чат**.

**Перемещение** [части] комментариев в чат — **норма**.

**Давность** вопроса **не должна играть роли**.

**Бан — не санкционирован**. **Сообщение** конкретному пользователь **с просьбой** ограничить число таких тревог в день (без указания конкретного количества) — **возможно**.

Answer (score 5):

К сожалению вы не показали, что за комментарии собственно говоря он помечает.

Так что я просто скажу, что я думаю об этом в принципе:

- Ненужные комментарии к старому ответы нужно удалять. Что такое ненужные? Пример:

  > четта нифига нироботает (((
  > Вы точно запустили этот код из под рута?
  > АААААА!!!!!! ТОЧНА!!!!!! ПАСИБ ТЕ ПЕРИЦ!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
- Ну а полезные комменты, то есть те которые со смыслом или полезное уточнение, или еще что-то удалять не надо. Пример:

  > Ну ведь здесь можно и покрасивее, и поправильнее написать: `','.join(i for i in lst if i not in lst2 and i <10)`. 
  > Ну да, но я так написал, чтобы было понятнее для новичка, пусть и в 10 строк, но более ясно. )

Решения эти довольно субъективны — и их принимает модератор, нет смысла обсуждать это с сообществом без примера.

Answer (score 3):

Старые комментарии могут вводить в заблуждение, особенно если часть диалога уже удалена. Комментарии, относящиеся к ней, на мой взгляд точно не нужны.

Комментарии к вопросам, на которые уже есть принятый ответ, уже смысла не имеют, т. к. вопрос решен.

Комментарии, являющиеся ответом, на мой взгляд можно переносить в ответ с пометкой *общий*.

Comment: Переносить можно, но этим не должен заниматься модератор. Это сначала может сделать пользователь по всей проформе, и уже потом флагнуть комментарий.